# Problem ipsec site to site ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall

I am receiving this error when I try to establish an ipsec site to site vpn:

```
PSEC: Parsing PFKey GETSPI message
IPSEC: Creating IPsec SA
IPSEC: Getting the inbound SPI
IPSEC: New embryonic SA created @ 0x00007fffa372dc60,
    SCB: 0x9C3EF830,
    Direction: inbound
    SPI      : 0x17951BCF
    Session ID: 0x00AA2000
    VPIF num  : 0x00000002
    Tunnel type: l2l
    Protocol   : esp
    Lifetime   : 240 seconds

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Looking for crypto map matching 5-tuple: Prot=1, 
saddr=10.0.100.2, sport=45638, daddr=192.168.120.100, dport=45638

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Checking crypto map outside_map 10: matched.
Jul 24 08:20:49 [IKE COMMON DEBUG]Duplicate entry already in Tunnel Manager

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Looking for crypto map matching 5-tuple: Prot=1, saddr=10.0.100.2, sport=45638, daddr=192.168.120.100, dport=45638

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Checking crypto map outside_map 10: matched.
Jul 24 08:20:50 [IKE COMMON DEBUG]Duplicate entry already in Tunnel Manager

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Looking for crypto map matching 5-tuple: Prot=1, saddr=10.0.100.2, sport=45638, daddr=192.168.120.100, dport=45638

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Checking crypto map outside_map 10: matched.
Jul 24 08:20:51 [IKE COMMON DEBUG]Duplicate entry already in Tunnel Manager

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Looking for crypto map matching 5-tuple: Prot=1, saddr=10.0.100.2, sport=45638, daddr=192.168.120.100, dport=45638

IPSEC(crypto_map_check)-3: Checking crypto map outside_map 10: matched.
Jul 24 08:20:52 [IKE COMMON DEBUG]Duplicate entry already in Tunnel Manager

Jul 24 08:21:20 [IKE COMMON DEBUG]IKEv1 was unsuccessful at setting up a tunnel.  Map Tag = outside_map.  Map Sequence Number = 10.

Jul 24 08:21:20 [IKE COMMON DEBUG]Tunnel Manager has failed to establish an L2L SA.  All configured IKE versions failed to establish the tunnel. Map Tag= outside_map.  Map Sequence Number = 10.

Jul 24 08:21:20 [IKE COMMON DEBUG]Tunnel Manager Removed entry.  Map Tag = outside_map.  Map Sequence Number = 10.

IPSEC: Received a PFKey message from IKE

IPSEC: Destroy current inbound SPI: 0x17951BCF
```

---

it never reaches `Phase 1 succeed`

```
FWASA(config)# show isakmp sa

IKEv1 SAs:

   Active SA: 1
    Rekey SA: 0 (A tunnel will report 1 Active and 1 Rekey SA during rekey)
Total IKE SA: 1

1   IKE Peer: 217.117.146.118
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE
```

How can I resolve this problem?

---

this is my config

```
ASA Version 8.6(1)2
!
hostname FW-VPN-IPS
domain-name name.sn
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.100.254 255.255.255.0
!
boot system disk0:/asa861-2-smp-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
dns server-group DefaultDNS
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network Remote-ASA
 host 217.X.X.X
object network RA-VPN-local
 subnet 10.0.100.0 255.255.255.0
 object network Remote-servers
 host 192.168.120.100
access-list Security-ACL extended permit ip 10.0.100.0 255.255.255.0 host 192.168.120.100
access-list Security-ACL extended permit ip host 192.168.120.100 10.0.100.0 255.255.255.0
access-list Interesting-traffic extended permit ip 10.0.100.0 255.255.255.0 host 192.168.120.100
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu management 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 10 burst-size 10
icmp permit any outside
icmp permit any inside
asdm image disk0:/asdm-66114.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
nat (outside,outside) source static RA-VPN-local RA-VPN-local destination static Remote-servers Remote-servers no-proxy-arp route-lookup
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set TRANS1 esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES-SHA
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal secure
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto map OUTSIDE_map 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto map map002 3 match address Interesting-traffic
crypto map map002 3 set peer 217.X.X.X
crypto map map002 3 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map 10 match address Interesting-traffic
crypto map outside_map 10 set pfs
crypto map outside_map 10 set peer 217.X.X.X
crypto map outside_map 10 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map 10 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES-SHA DES 3DES AES AES192 AES256
secure
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp identity address
crypto isakmp disconnect-notify
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 enable inside
crypto ikev1 policy 1
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
console timeout 0
no threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ssl-clientless
group-policy RA-VPN-Group internal
group-policy RA-VPN-Group attributes
 vpn-filter value Security-ACL
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1
 pfs enable
group-policy L2L-policy internal
group-policy L2L-policy attributes
 vpn-filter value Security-ACL
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2
tunnel-group DefaultL2LGroup ipsec-attributes
 isakmp keepalive disable
tunnel-group 217.X.X.X type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 217.X.X.X general-attributes
 default-group-policy L2L-policy
tunnel-group 217.X.X.X ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 isakmp keepalive disable
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
no tunnel-group-map enable ou
tunnel-group-map default-group 217.X.X.X
!
```

Comment: Why do you use both IKEv1 and IKEv2?

Comment: I do the test witk ikev1 only but it didn t work